# value of <meter> will be the value from the localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

how to make value of `<meter>` will be the value from the localStorage in HTML5 or JavaScript?
whenever I refresh my browser the value in the localstorage is constant but the meter becomes 100 or full again instead of retaining its last place.

codes for html :

```
<meter id="lifebar" min=0 max=100 value=100></meter>
```

JS codes for localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("life", document.getElementById("lifebar").value);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: _“but the meter becomes 100 or full again”_ – and that surprises you why exactly? You have explicitly stated `value=100` in your HTML code, so why would _anything else_ magically happen? Read the value from localstorage, and then _set_ it on the element via JavaScript.

Comment: I know that in the first place I just put it like that. I'm just showing what my code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can implement a meter that is 'unaffected' by page reload -

For example:

```
var value;
var meter = document.getElementById('myMeter');

function initMeter() {

    //read previous value if any, or start from 0    
    value = localStorage.getItem('value');
    if (value === null) value = 0;

    //update meter with value loaded or inited
    meter.setAttribute('value', value);
}

//demo loop
function demoProgress() {

    //update meter on screen
    meter.setAttribute('value', value++);

    //when we have reached max, trigger something.
    //here we just repeat for demo
    if (value === 100) value = 0; //trigger complete here..

    //save current value to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('value', value);

    //for loop
    setTimeout(demoProgress, 300);
}

// init meter and start loop
initMeter();
demoProgress();
```

Working demo (hit Run to reload page and see progress bar continues from where it left off):
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/CAdcq/

Comment: From what the OP has said, it doesn't look like the `min` or `max` values need to be stored in `localStorage`.